# Node.js : npm error, node file v8.h for node-gyp is not working

Tags: node.js

I am new to this website, and I may make mistakes while writing this question. Please tell me, in order to improve.

I work on Windows 10.

I am learning node.js, and I was looking for socket.io on npm. After searching for ages on the web, I didn't find an answer for a problem like mine. So, maybe it is easy to fix, but I am not familiar with IT in general.
Here is my problem, I write in my powershell: npm intall socket.io
A thousand error sentences appear on my powershell :

```
C:\Users\Rocp\.node-gyp\4.2.2\include\node\v8.h(336): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\U
sers\Rocp\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modul
es\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Rocp\.node-gyp\4.2.2\include\node\v8.h(336): error C2059: syntax error : 'using' [C:\Users\Rocp\node_modules\s
ocket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\buff
erutil.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Rocp\.node-gyp\4.2.2\include\node\v8.h(469): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\U
sers\Rocp\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modul
es\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
...
until C:\users\Rocp\.node-gyp\4.2.2\include\node\v8.h (3478)
```

Moreover, it shows :

> Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe`
> failed with exit code: 1

Please note that I followed the tutorial for problems with npm :

- I downloaded python 2.7.3 and set it with: npm config set python c:/python27/python.exe
- I downloaded MSVS 2012 express, and I set it in the config too.

Comment: If you haven't, update NodeJS and NPM.

Comment: I uninstalled/reinstalled nodejs this morning